# Reading nested json in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I am newbie to AngularJS. I have JSON file which I have to fetch using angularjs!

JSON File

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "students": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Bill",
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Steve",
        }
        ],
      "exstudent": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Woz",
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Jonathan",
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Controller part snippet -

```
 $http.get('json/somedata.json').success(function (data){

        $scope.name = data.records.student.name;
        $scope.exname = data.records.exstudent.name;

        });


  }])
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat = "browse in name">
  {{browse.student.name}}
</div>
```

Which part I am doing wrong? I think the problem is with ng-repeat! 
Need Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `data.records.students.name` as `students` is an `Array`.

You can however store its data into your `$scope` and use it in the `ng-repeat`:

```
$http.get('json/config.json').success(function (data){
    $scope.students = data.records.students;
    $scope.exstudents = data.records.exstudent;
});
```

Then in your HTML use the `ng-repeat` like this:

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="student in students">
    {{student.name}}
</div>
```